# Html2Canvas: Each click renders a different result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I'm experiencing an issue with html2canvas plugin (https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) . For some reason, when I ask to generate the canvas, each click generate a different result.

As you can see here, 10 different tests generate different results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2HtI.png

The expected result is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXcX1.png

I'm not using any CSS3 advanced attribute, and this is a very simple HTML page.

Any ideas on what may be happening? The same problem happens if I ask to generate a base64 image on another browser tab.

I'm testing on Firefox 40 for Mac OS X.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us any of your code?

Comment: I'm using the exact same code they're using on the demo page: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html